# Haskell if statement is not working properly

Tags: list, haskell, if-statement

Very simple code. It will get the third last item from a list.

```
list numbers = if length numbers > 3
then numbers!!(length numbers - 3) 

else "length must be greater than 2"
```

When i try to run it on the GHCI I keep getting this error however,

*Main> list [2,3,4]

```
<interactive>:65:7: No instance for (Num [Char])
 arising from the literal     `2'
 Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Char])
In the expression: 2
In the first argument of `list', namely `[2, 3, 4]'
In the expression: list [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types of the two expressions in the `then` and `else` clause must match. Since one side of the branch returns a list element, and the other side returns a string, ghci concludes that the list elements must be strings. But you specified `[2,3,4]`, whose elements are numbers. Hence the complaint: it doesn't know how to turn a number into a `String`.

Consider returning a `Maybe` or `Either` value instead:

```
list numbers = if length numbers > 3
    then Right (numbers!!(length numbers - 3))
    else Left "length must be greater than 2" -- sic: 3, not 2
```

Comment: The variables types have to be the same in an if-else statement? This language is so trippy

Comment: @bossrevs if-else is an expression that evaluates to a value. Many programming languages have the same semantics. Haskell might be 'strange' in various ways, but this isn't one of them

Comment: @bossrevs Sure. What should be the type of an expression like `if foo then True else LT` where the `then` and `else` clauses don't match? It's not limited to Haskell, either; it's just that in most other languages `if`/`then`/`else` is a statement, not an expression, and you can think of "statement" as its own type (and there is a default statement that does nothing inserted as an `else` branch if you don't specify one).

Comment: Oh ofcourse, the function has only 1 return type. Opps. Thanks for your help

Comment: @bossrevs Note that Haskell's if-then-else is similar to C/Java/... ternary operators `b ? x : y` , which require `x,y` to share the same type, like Haskell. So Haskell is actually not different from all the other languages in this aspect.